# sqlite database error : malformed disk image : not going away

Tags: database, sqlite

I have been working with a database ( related to an android app) now this specific database has all my messages stored and i have no backup saved. when i'm trying to import this im getting the error ' malformed disk image'.
i tried all the procedures given on the net( import/export , dumping to an sql file everything'the error i'm getting is

```
          ***error near line 80376 messages.remote_key_id may not be NULL***
```

I can't believe that out of everything all my messages will be lost because of just one small error.
is there anyway i can just delete the record?
i tried opening the file through sqlite3 database browser but there , the record numbers stop at 800901.
so what is the line '83376' that it is pointing to?
please help
i really need to make this work.

Comment: This is not a record number; it is a line number in the source code of your application.

Comment: How do I correct that?

Comment: That depends on your application. In general, restore from the backup.

Comment: Actually it is the backup that's corrupt. The application is whatsapp . Nothing can be done?